# Dependency inversion (from S.O.L.I.D principles) in C++

Tags: c++, oop, solid-principles, dependency-inversion

After reading and watching much about SOLID principles I was very keen to use these principles in my work (mostly C++ development) since I do think they are good principles and that they indeed will bring much benefit to the quality of my code, readability, testability, reuse and maintainability.
But I have real hard time with the 'D' (Dependency inversion).
This principal states that:
A. High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.
B. Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions.

Let me explain by example:
Lets say I am writing the following interface:

```
    class SOLIDInterface {
      //usual stuff with constructor, destructor, don't copy etc
      public:
      virtual void setSomeString(const std::string &someString) = 0;
    };
```

(for the sake of simplicity please ignore the other things needed for a "correct interface" such as non virutal publics, private virtuals etc, its not part of the problem.)

notice, that setSomeString() is taking an std::string.
But that breaks the above principal since std::string is an implementation.
Java and C# don't have that problem since the language offers interfaces to all the complex common types such as string and containers.
C++ does not offer that.
Now, C++ does offer the possibility to write this interface in such a way that I could write an 'IString' interface that would take any implementation that will support an std::string interface using type erasure 
(Very good article: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html)

So the implementation could use STL (std::string) or Qt (QString), or my own string implementation or something else.
Like it should be.

But this means, that if I (and not only I but all C++ developers) want to write C++ API which obeys SOLID design principles ('D' included), I will have to implement a LOT of code to accommodate all the common non natural types.
Beyond being not realistic in terms of effort, this solution has other problems such as - what if STL changes?(for this example)
And its not really a solution since STL is not implementing IString, rather IString is abstracting STL, so even if I were to create such an interface the principal problem remains.
(I am not even getting into issues such as this adds polymorphic overhead, which for some systems, depending on size and HW requirements may not be acceptable)

So may question is:
Am I missing something here (which I guess the true answer, but what?), is there a way to use Dependency inversion in C++ without writing a whole new interface layer for the common types *in a realistic way* - or are we doomed to write API which is always dependent on some implementation?

Thanks for your time!

From the first few comments I received so far I think a clarification is needed:
The selection of std::string was just an example.
It could be QString for that matter - I just took STL since it is the standard.
Its not even important that its a string type, it could be any common type.

I have selected the answer by Corristo not because he explicitly answered my question but because the extensive post (coupled with the other answers) allowed me to extract my answer from it implicitly, realizing that the discussion tends to drift from the actual question which is:
Can you implement Dependency inversion in C++ when you use basic complex types like strings and containers and basically any of the STL with an effort that makes sense. (and the last part is a very important element of the question).
Maybe I should have explicitly noted that I am after run-time polymorphism not compile time.
The clear answer is NO, its not possible.
It might have been possible if STL would have exposed abstract interfaces to their implementations (if there are indeed reasons that prevent the STL implementations to derive from these interfaces (say, performance)) then it still could have simply maintained these abstract interfaces to match the implementations).

For types that I have full control over, yes, there is no technical problem implementing the DIP.
But most likely any such interface (of my own) will still use a string or a container, forcing it to use either the STL implementation or another.
All the suggested solutions below are either not polymorphic in runtime, or/and are forcing quiet a some coding around the interface - when you think you have to do this for all these common types the practicality is simply not there.

If you think you know better, and you say it is possible to have what I described above then simply post the code proving it.
I dare you! :-)

Comment: I would not say a String is a modul.

Comment: `s/principal/principle/g`

Comment: I think you're really talking about the Standard Library rather than `C++` itself. `Java` has a strongly inheritance based, polymorphic standard library providing interfaces for everything. The `C++` standard libraries make much less use of polymorphism through inheritance and use *static* template meta-programming instead. I think it provides even less coupling than general *interfaces* do with added speed advantages. But it is a completely orthogonal philosophy.

Comment: @Galik: I guess you are using the word "polymorphism" to mean only run-time polymorphism?  But compile-time polymorphism is possible too.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, you are correct, I often forget there are other kings

Comment: std::string is being used to pass the values around, since something needs to be, but the internal string handling of each module doesn't need to be limited to that. You could be storing Qt strings or raw pointer strings, and neither module would know about what the other is using. you can also typedef the std::string and make a minimal version that only does the things you want, which can be switched in, instead of std::string

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks! :-)

Comment: @JasonLang that is however not the issue. The issue is the fact my interface depend on implementation, instead on abstraction. The "since something needs to be" in your comment which is important. That something I would like to be abstract. As I wrote, C++ allows this, but it create an effort which makes it unrealistic.

Comment: @Galik No, I was talking about C++. The orthogonal philosophy I think is a good point even thought I don't think its true since C++ is designed to be polymorphic as well. As you say, Java offers interfaces for everything on a language level, C++ does not, which I think is the root of the problem. As Ben Voigt below noted, seems this 'feature' will come in to C++ in the future, at least in some sort of a way.

Comment: @dkish: You're not understanding.  Java lets you get runtime polymorphism by writing an interface, and if the implementation didn't know about the interface, you're SOL.  C++ lets you get runtime polymorphism by writing an abstract base class, or in the future, compile-time polymorphism by writing a concept specification, or today, you get compile-time polymorphism and don't have to do anything at all.

Comment: For the specific case of strings, you can use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view). In a way this is similar to type erasure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Note that C++ is not an object-oriented programming language, but rather lets the programmer choose between many different paradigms. One of the key principles of C++ is that of zero-cost abstractions, which in particular entails to build abstractions in such a way that users don't pay for what they don't use.

The C#/Java style of defining interfaces with virtual methods that are then implemented by derived classes don't fall into that category though, because even if you don't need the polymorphic behavior, were `std::string` implementing a virtual interface, every call of one of its methods would incur a vtable lookup. This is unacceptable for classes in the C++ standard library supposed to be used in all kinds of settings.

### Defining interfaces without inheriting from an abstract interface class

Another problem with the C#/Java approach is that in most cases you don't actually care that something inherits from a particular abstract interface class and only need that the type you pass to a function supports the operations you use. Restricting accepted parameters to those inheriting from a particular interface class thus actually hinders reuse of existing components, and you often end up writing wrappers to make classes of one library conform to the interfaces of another - even when they already have the exact same member functions.

Together with the fact that inheritance-based polymorphism typically also entails heap allocations and reference semantics with all its problems regarding lifetime management, it is best to avoid inheriting from an abstract interface class in C++.

#### Generic templates for implicit interfaces

In C++ you can get compile-time polymorphism through templates.
In its simplest form, the interface that an object used in a templated function or class need to conform to is not actually specified in C++ code, but implied by what functions are called on them.

This is the approach used in the STL, and it is really flexible. Take `std::vector` for example. There the requirements on the value type `T` of objects you store in it are dependent on what operations you perform on the vector. This allows e.g. to store move-only types as long as you don't use any of the operations that need to make a copy. In such a case, defining an interface that the value types needs to conform to would greatly reduce the usefulness of `std::vector`, because you'd either need to remove methods that require copies or you'd need to exclude move-only types from being stored in it.

That doesn't mean you can't use dependency inversion, though: The common [Button-Lamp example](http://stg-tud.github.io/sedc/Lecture/ws13-14/3.5-DIP.html#mode=document) for dependency inversion implemented with templates would look like this:

```
class Lamp {
public:
    void activate();
    void deactivate();
};

template <typename T>
class Button {
    Button(T& switchable)
        : _switchable(&switchable) {
    }

    void toggle() {
        if (_buttonIsInOnPosition) {
            _switchable->deactivate();
            _buttonIsInOnPosition = false;
        } else {
            _switchable->activate();
            _buttonIsInOnPosition = true;
        }      
    }

private:
   bool _buttonIsInOnPosition{false};
   T* _switchable;  
}

int main() {
   Lamp l;
   Button<Lamp> b(l)

   b.toggle();
}
```

Here `Button<T>::toggle` implicitly relies on a `Switchable` interface, requiring `T` to have member functions `T::activate` and `T::deactivate`. Since `Lamp` happens to implement that interface it can be used with the `Button` class. Of course, in real code you would also state these requirements on `T` in the documentation of the `Button` class so that users don't need to look up the implementation.

Similarly, you could also declare your `setSomeString` method as

```
template <typename String>
void setSomeString(String const& string);
```

and then this will work with all types that implement all the methods you used in the implementation of `setSomeString`, hence only relying on an abstract - although implicit - interface.

As always, there are some downsides to consider:

- In the string example, assuming you only make use of `.begin()` and `.end()` member functions returning iterators that return a `char` when dereferenced (e.g. to copy it into the classes' local, concrete string data member), you can also accidentally pass a `std::vector<char>` to it, even though it isn't technically a string. If you consider this a problem is arguable, in a way this can also be seen as the epitome of relying only on abstractions.
- If you pass an object of a type that doesn't have the required (member) functions, then you can end up with horrible compiler error messages that make it very hard to find the source of the error.
- Only in very limited cases it is possible to separate the interface of a templated class or function from its implementation, as is typically done with separate `.h` and `.cpp` files. This can thus lead to longer compile times.

#### Defining interfaces with the Concepts TS

if you really care about types used in templated functions and classes to conform to a fixed interface, regardless of what you actually use, there are ways to restrict the template parameters only to types conforming to a certain interface with `std::enable_if`, but these are very verbose and unreadable. In order to make this kind of generic programming easier, the Concepts TS allows to actually define interfaces that are checked by the compiler and thus greatly improves diagnostics. With the Concepts TS, the Button-Lamp example from above translates to

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Switchable = requires(T t) {
    t.activate();
    t.deactivate();
};

// Lamp as before

template <Switchable T>
class Button {
public:
    Button(T&);    // implementation as before
    void toggle(); // implementation as before
private:
    T* _switchable;
    bool _buttonIsInOnPosition{false};
};
```

If you can't use the Concepts TS (it is only implemented in GCC right now), the closest you can get is the [Boost.ConceptCheck](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) library.

### Type erasure for runtime polymorphism

There is one case where compile-time polymorphism doesn't suffice, and that is when the types you pass to or get from a particular function aren't fully determined at compile-time but depend on runtime parameters (e.g. from a config file, command-line arguments passed to the executable or even the value of a parameter passed to the function itself).

If you need to store objects (even in a variable) of a type dependent on runtime parameters, the traditional approach is to store pointers to a common base class instead and to use dynamic dispatch via virtual member functions to get the behavior you need. But this still suffers from the problem described before: You can't use types that effectively do what you need but were defined in an external library, and thus don't inherit from the base class you defined. So you have to write a wrapper class.

Or you do what you described in your question and create a type-erasure class.
An example from the standard library is `std::function`. You declare only the interface of the function and it can store arbitrary function pointers and callables that have that interface. In general, writing a type erasure class can be quite tedious, so I refrain from giving an example of a type-erasing `Switchable` here, but I can highly recommend Sean Parent's talk [Inheritance is the base class of evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIhUE5uUFOA), where he demonstrates the technique for "Drawable" objects and explores what you can build on top of it in just over 20 minutes.

There are libraries that help writing type-erasure classes though, e.g. Louis Dionne's experimental [dyno](https://github.com/ldionne/dyno), where you define the interface via what he calls "concept maps" directly in C++ code, or Zach Laine's [emtypen](https://github.com/tzlaine/type_erasure/tree/master/emtypen) which uses a python tool to create the type erasure classes from a C++ header file you provide. The latter also comes with a [CppCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0I0FD3N5cgM) describing the features as well as the general idea and how to use it.

### Conclusion

Inheriting from a common base class just to define interfaces, while easy, leads to many problems that can be avoided using different approaches:

- (Constrained) templates allow for compile-time polymorphism, which is sufficient for the majority of cases, but can lead to hard-to-understand compiler errors when used with types that don't conform to the interface.
- If you need runtime polymorphism (which actually is rather rare in my experience), you can use type-erasure classes.

So even though the classes in the STL and other C++ libraries rarely derive from an abstract interface, you can still apply dependency inversion with one of the two methods described above if you really want to.

But as always, use good judgment on a case-by-case basis whether you really need the abstraction or if it is better to simply use a concrete type. The string example you brought up is one where I'd go with concrete types, simply because the different string classes don't share a common interface (e.g. `std::string` has `.find()`, but `QString`s version of the same function is called `.contains()`). It might be just as much effort to write wrapper classes for both as it is to write a conversion function and to use that at well-defined boundaries within the project.

Comment: Thanks for a very through and comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, but C++ lets you write code that is independent of a particular implementation without actually using inheritance.

`std::string` itself is a good example... it's actually a typedef for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`.  Which allows you to create strings using other allocators if you choose (or mock the allocator object in order to measure number of calls, if you like).  There just isn't any explicit interface like an `IAllocator`, because C++ templates use duck-typing.

A future version of C++ will support explicit description of the interface a template parameter must adhere to -- this feature is called concepts -- but just using duck-typing enables decoupling without requiring redundant interface definitions.

And because C++ performs optimization *after* instantiation of templates, there's no polymorphic overhead.

Now, when you do have virtual functions, you'll need to commit to a particular type, because the virtual-table layout doesn't accommodate use of templates each of which generates an arbitrary number of instances each of which require separate dispatch.  But when using templates, you'll won't need virtual functions nearly as much as e.g. Java does, so in practice this isn't a big problem.

Comment: Thanks for the details answer.
However, I am not sure it really answers my question.
For using duck-typing I need to write and implementation. I don't want to write an implementation, I want to write an Interface. I want to say WHAT my class can do, not HOW it should do it. Templates define HOW things get done, but don't care which type they work on as long as the type supports the methods called in the template.

Comment: You probably answered my question with the new C++ concepts. I derive from that, that for now, C++ forces me to be bound to an implementation when I write my interfaces and thus to violate the dependency inversion principle.

Comment: "don't care which type they work on as long as the type supports the methods called in the template" ... well, it's more than just methods, also operators and free-standing functions.  But that's pretty much the definition of decoupling -- any type that provides the right behavior can be used, independent of implementation.  The dependency is chosen by the external user that chooses the template parameters -- you don't get better dependency inversion than that.

Comment: When you say "I want to write an Interface. I want to say WHAT my class can do", go ahead and use a comment to describe the interface.  The C++  compiler doesn't need the description, so put it where programmers can find it.

Comment: But I can't use comments to enforce my class's API, and its important that I can do that. I want the compiler to care about the signatures of the methods of my interface that implementations of my interface implement. I also want other software to know what they can expect from other implementations of my interface even if they don't have them - all things one uses interfaces for - smothering comments can't deliver.

Comment: @dkish: So your complaint is that C++ fails at being Java, not that C++ fails at dependency inversion.

Comment: "any type that provides the right behavior can be used, independent of implementation." Hmm.. so what I understand is, that I should turn my interface to a template class with pure virtuals? I guess that could work, I'll have to think about it...

Comment: "So your complaint is that C++ fails at being Java, not that C++ fails at dependency inversion." I am not complaining, I am just trying to understand. And I don't agree - nothing in what you said so far had type inversion satisfied - type decoupling is not type inversion. In that sense Java does make it easier. C++ allows it technically, but in practice its hard to implement in terms of effort needed. P.S Thanks so much for your time and patience!

Comment: @dkish: If you want to be Java-like, you don't need templates at all, just an abstract class with pure virtuals.  But this makes the implementation depend on the consumer (you have to know what pointer type the consumer requires and derive from that).  C++ duck typing avoids that.  You're right that decoupling is not identical to inversion, but C++ definitely provides inversion -- the template parameters are supplied by the ultimate user, not by either the library or the consumer.  It's not runtime dependency injection; it is inversion (SOLID).  Did you really mean to ask about injection?